# Minkowski to Euclidean

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, wick-rotation

When dealing with solutions to Einstein's equations given by a 4d metric with signature $(-,+,+,+)$, we're able to move to Euclidean space using some transformation so that our signature is now $(+,+,+,+)$ and our metric is changed slightly different.

What I'm worried about is what this does to the properties of my metric. When I go to Euclidean space, I am able to deduce some nice relations, however, $\textbf{do these relations hold for my original metric?}$ e.g. let's say I'm interested in the metric

$$ds_1^2=-V_1dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{V_1}+W_1d\Omega^2,$$

where $d\Omega^2$ is metric on $S^2$. Now my metric in Euclidean space is

$$ds_2^2=+V_2dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{V_2}+W_2d\Omega^2.$$

where $V_1(a,b,c)=V_2(i a,b,c)$ and for $V_2$ I have some cool relation (e.g. $V_2(a=b)=0$, for $i$ the imaginary number. How can I relate this to the properties of $V_1$ if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real parameters? The reverse transformation gives $V_1(-i a=b)=0$, but I don't know how to interrupt this $a$ and $b$ are real.

Perhaps I haven't throughout deeply enough about it yet and it's a naive question, but I don't think I yet comprehensively understand what this transformation means for the properties of our space.

Comment: yes they do, with a reverse wick rotation back to *real time*

Comment: @NikosM. But this, for me, implies imaginary mass. So do I discard this relation?

Comment: What relation exactly is that? i dont see mass in the question

Comment: @NikosM. Sorry I'm not referring to any metric in particular. When I said $a$ and $b$ in the question I meant they could be anything - mass, radius, …  Probably should have mentioned that whatever the metric, it's for a black hole

Comment: it is very simple really, think of it like multiplying one dimension by a number (which happens to be imaginary), or like changing scale, this is the algebraic part, as such nothing should be "wrong", the physical interpretation is another thing

Comment: @NikosM. So it's worthless (in the physical sense) talking about the properties of a metric in Euclidean space when these properties, when translated back to Minkowski space, make no physical sense?

Comment: No it is not worthless (and there is 1-1 correspondence), for example euclidean QFts have better (mathematical) properties (which when translated back through wick rotation) allow for results to ordinary QFTs, also analytical treatment of euclidean space-time is easier, and wick rotation is interesting in itself, maybe some relation of yours is wrong or not correctly translated?

Comment: @NikosM. So right now (excluding unnecessary lengthy details), after going to Euclidean space using the transformations $t-it$ and $a \to ia$, where $a$ is some parameter I don't know the meaning of, I get a condition for the mass which is $m = a-a^3$ (don't ask why I have this condition, I haven't figured out the real reason yet but I know that I need it). But now going back to Minkowski, $a \to -ia$, this implies $m = -i(a+a^3)$. So I don't understand the meaning of this condition.

Comment: sorry dont understand either, it seems your problem is with the $a$ parameter, and i dont understand what it is supposed to mean, or why it needs to be wick-rotated too

Comment: on second thought, try using these transformations: $t \to ikt$ and $a \to ika$, where $k$ is some parameter, then at the end, when you want to revert back to real-time, just set $k=-i$, effectively, this *trick* keeps track of what is happening and one does not actually *wick rotate* at all (assuming $k=-i$ always)

Comment: Yes this is actually what I've started to consider since asking this question. So $V_1$ (Minkowski) is independent of $t$, so when I set $a \to ia$, I get $V_2$ (Euclidean). $V_2$ is much nicer and I can get the condition $m=a-a^3$ from it. However this means nothing physical really because it doesn't make sense in Minkowkski as it says real(mass)=imaginary. Is introducing this parameter $k$ physically sound though? I don't know how to interpret the condition if it doesn't work in Minkowski space.

Comment: yes think of it like this: $t \to (i)(-i)t$ etc.. so in effect nothing changes, you just leave the $-i$ factor as $k$ and replace it in the end, just to keep track of what is happening, if it doesnt work it means the error is somewhere else (maybe in some formulas)

Comment: Thanks, it sounds good to me. I mean I'm trying to think about it and all I can conclude is that it's simply a "trick" to make things easier. Because essentially you're doing absolutely nothing, $a \to a$